# How to use update function in controller when I don't need extra parameters?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting a Missing required parameters for [Route: profiel.update] [URI: profiel/{profiel}] error. But I don't need the parameter.

I'm calling my function like this

```
 <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="{{ action('SettingsController@update') }}">
```

And this is the update function in the controller

```
$settings = Settings::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

$settings->taal = $request->input('taal');
$settings->valuta = $request->input('valuta');
return redirect('profiel');
```

How can I still use this function?

Comment: share your route codes that contain SettingsController@update

Comment: @Mohammadb This is my route  Route::resource('profiel', 'SettingsController');

Comment: Did you create your controller using —resource ??

Comment: @CodeBoyCode I did it like this 'php artisan make:model Settings -mcr'

Comment: `$settings->save();` before `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Laravel Document : [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers)

you have to use parameter if you use resource controller

instead of resource, you can create another route

```
Route::post('profileupdate','SettingsController@upd')->name('profile_update');
```

and controller upd:

```
public function upd()
{
$settings = Settings::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

$settings->taal = $request->input('taal');
$settings->valuta = $request->input('valuta');
return redirect('profiel');
}
```

and change form action:

```
 <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="{{ route('profile_update') }}">
```